# Fixed Effects model

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to understand the fixed effects model.

$ Y = D\alpha + X\beta + \epsilon$

Where

$\alpha$ is the fixed time invariant effect.

If we model this using Frisch Waugh lovell partitioning out, we get

$\hat{\beta}$ = $[X'M_{d}X]^{-1} X'M_{d}Y$

where $M_{d}$ is = $I - D(D'D)^{-1}D'$

Now, in the next step, the books say that

$M_{d}$ = $I - (1/T)i'i$ = $M_{0}$

where i is a unit vector

I am unable to understand how is $M_{d}$ = $M_{o}$

This is important because then we simply regress demeaned Y on demeaned X.

Can someone help me understand this step?